# Is there a limit to the number of CKReferenced records in CloudKit?

Tags: ios, icloud, cloudkit, ckreference

I am trying to store groups of contacts in CloudKit, and I am getting an error back if I try to create a large group of records, CKReferenced to a single group record.

The limit appears to be around 700 or so records.

Has anyone else seen a similar result, or can confirm the existence (or non-existence) of a limit? I can't find anything in the docs, or through Google.

NOTE: I am already splitting the records I submit into batches of 400 or less, as that seems to be a hard limit.

Comment: what error do you get? Is it a CKErrorCode.LimitExceeded ? First cast the record using:         let errorCode:CKErrorCode = CKErrorCode(rawValue: error!.code)!

Comment: it is 
Limit Exceeded. server message = "Limit exceeded for number of owning references to single record"

Comment: If that's only 700 or so, then it would be horrible. The app that I am working on will hit that limit in production. Then instead of a CKReference, you should use a string with the ID. The only disadvantage is that you won't have automatic deletions if the parent record is removed.

Comment: Can you test your app with those sort of large relationships? It would be useful to see if someone else has the same problem.

Comment: I will do a test later this evening (in about 5 hours) I will also test if it varies per CKReferenceAction (non and DeleteSelf)

Comment: That was a nice test to do... I added a loop in my app that the moment a message was send it would do it 100 times. I had no problem adding 1000 records. Every record had 2 CKReference fields. I did send the records 1 by 1, but still in my case I did not receive any errors. I could also query the 1000 records without any problem. This is the code that I had put in a 1...100 loop: https://github.com/evermeer/EVCloudKitDao/blob/f2e6c70d4b8a1d999ee014ba642a0d5c0f04f984/AppMessage/AppMessage/Controlers/ChatViewController.swift#L208-208

Comment: Thanks Edwin, that's very interesting. I'll try 1 by 1 and see if that makes a difference (I have tried in in 400s and 100s, and it refused at 400 and 700 for me in each case so it looked like maybe a 750 limit. I'll try your test code too and let you know how I get on.

Comment: I tried adding members to cloudkit individually, and it stopped at exactly 750.

I tried to add another member manually using the CloudKit dashboard, and it showed "Unexpected server error. ATOMIC_FAILURE: Limit exceeded for number of owning references..." in a pop-up error message.

I am using a private zone, with DeleteSelf set. Are you doing the same?

Comment: Ah, i was using a public zone. Will try a private tomorow.

Comment: I just saved 1000 records to my private database with 2 CKReferences to the same record. I did not encounter any error. I could find all records in the CloudKit dashboard. So there should be some special case where it goes wrong. I have all fields involved set to queryable in the dashboard. you too?

Comment: What happened Peter; Did you get to the bottom of this?

Comment: I couldn't get past the limit, i'm not sure why. it was not unreasonable for me to limit my group size to 500 contacts, anyway.

Comment: I am getting "Limit exceeded for number of owning references to single record" now also...

Answer (score 5):

Yes & no - it depends on whether the `CKReferences` have a `CKReferenceAction` of `deleteSelf`.

In the [CloudKit Web Services Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloutKitWebServicesReference/PropertyMetrics/PropertyMetrics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015240-CH23-SW1)*, Apple lists the following limit:

> Maximum number of source references to a single target where the action is delete self = 750

This may explain why EVCloudKitDao was able to exceed this limit (in the comments above) - [its CKReferences were previously created with a CKReferenceAction of `None`](https://github.com/evermeer/EVCloudKitDao/commit/14c9da0b7ff7d93ce0cc6376062c453b0439c2b3#diff-bb760a3cef5798634fd8b505a72e6d79).

*Despite the only mention of this limit being in the CloudKit Web Services documentation, the [Designing for CloudKit reference links to it](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/DesigningforCloudKit/DesigningforCloudKit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012094-CH9-SW6), and it seems to be a server-side limit that applies regardless of which CloudKit API you are using.*

Comment: I am having this exact issue.  Thanks for the answer or I would have spent who knows how much time figuring this out.  I changed it from `.DeleteSelf` to `.None` and my 1000->1 and 5000->1 CKRecord->CkReference test works fine now.  However, I had to figure out how to do the cascade delete myself by hand.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's either that or partition your records into logical zones (as you can delete an entire zone - and the records it contains - in a single CKModifyRecordZonesOperation.)

Comment: There is one other way around, and that is to not have a single group object, but to have a small tree of group objects (e.g. subdirectories). This is how Git and other apps avoid too many files in a directory; they use the first two letters of the file name as a directory name. You could do something similar in your CK model.

Comment: @DrewMcCormack: Have you tested that deleting the root record of a tree in which the total number of cascading deletions is greater than 750 (as a result of .deleteSelf between different references) successfully deletes all the records? What's the highest limit that you have tested? (Am curious and may dig into this to see if I can hit an internal CloudKit limit, as there appear to be for some other things.)

Comment: I have not tested this, no, so would be worth doing. But I am of the opinion that the limit has to do with some table used internally to track the cascading references, and is a per record limit. I am not aware of any limit on the total number of these references, or the number that can be triggered in a single cascade of deletions.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me... Is splitting up the kid objects really a solution (apart from goint to `.None`? I always just assumed that a "kid" object always had to be created in the same zone as its parent object... not true?

Comment: Btw an updated link is here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitWebServicesReference/PropertyMetrics.html

Comment: @Coder1224 you mean that when I change reference from `DELETESELF` to `NONE` then the limit increase to 5 000 or even more?

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk Yes the limit goes up, possibly to unlimited??  In my case I tested with 5000 references.

Comment: @Coder1224 how did you do the cascade delete? so the client not sends the server the deletes it needs?